# Generate .map file with clang and lld

Tags: qt, clang, lld

I use Qt, clang and lld. Is there any way to generate .map in my case?
`-Wl,-Map=output.map`
didn't work out for me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

In a case if someone will face this problem.

```
$(LDFLAGS_MOD) -lm -Wl,-map,$@.map $(LDFLAGS_EXTRA)
```

helped me

Answer (score 3):

I have use

```
-Wl,-Map,output.map
```

(-Map with capital letter M) works for me in Clang linker flags.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).